# How to get rid of brackets in a JSON array?

Tags: node.js, json, openweathermap

so i'm pretty much new to Node.js, what i'm trying to do is use OpenWeatherMap to gather weather data and then print them to the console... however i've run into a weird issue that I just can't solve, despite hours of research

So, reading weather data from the JSON is simple enough, except for one group of items, here is a picture:
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcbPG.png)

As you can see, it reads 'undefined 12.5' while it gets temperature fine, the actual description though is undefined even though it's right there, taking a look at the JSON file OpenWeatherMap wrote, there is something strange

```
{
"coord": {
"lon": -1.61,
"lat": 54.98
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 876,
"main": "Haze",
"description": "haze",
"icon": "50d"
}
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
"temp": 12.2,
"pressure": 1014,
"humidity": 71,
"temp_min": 11,
"temp_max": 14
}
```

As you can see, the weather items have brackets for some reason, removing them manually fixes the problem and they can be read perfectly, however, how can I fix the problem so they are not there in the first place? What am I doing wrong? If you can think of any solutions to this problem

This is how I gather the data and use them:

```
        fs.writeFile('uk.json', JSON.stringify(currentWeather, null, 2), (error) => {
        if (error) throw err;
        console.log('Weather data written');
        var uk = require('./uk.json');
        console.log(uk.weather.main + ' ' + uk.main.temp);
    })
```

I'm new to Node.js and the only programming experience I have is Visual Basic, so please don't get too technical with me, try to explain it nicely and easy to understand for newbies if possible, thank you for your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weather is an array, so instead of "removing the brackets", you should retrieve your data as if you get it from an array (which you do).

You ask for the `main`  and `temp` part in the weather array, but you want those parts from the first element in the array. see e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: Also, since the data is in an array, you should probably assume that some dataset in the future might have multiple weather objects, and handle that appropriately.